# Improve AutoCompleteBox with PhoneTextBox features

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, autocompletebox

Is there a way to replace the default TextBox with a PhoneTextBox into an AutoCompleteBox control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the source of AutoCompeteBox from Silverlight toolkit and go crazy. Find and replace TextBox with PhoneTextBox .

Source can be found here 
http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest

Navigate to Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit / AutoCompleteBox for code
and Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.WP7 / Themes / Generic.xaml for xaml

Comment: I thought there was an easier way. Anyway, thank you for your answer!